# How to delete data from multiple tables in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with deleting data from my database. I have several tables connected by FK. I just thought it would be the same as inserting data. But it seems it's not the same.

Here is my code:

```
DELETE FROM uzivatel, inzerat_nabizim, lokalita_nabizim, pronajem_pokoj_nabizim, osoba_nabizim, typ_pokoje_nabizim, vybaveni_pokoj_nabizim, zarizeni_byt_nabizim
                     WHERE uzivatel.id_uzivatel = '$id_uzivatel'
                     AND inzerat_nabizim.id_uzivatel = uzivatel.id_uzivatel
                     AND pronajem_pokoj_nabizim.id_inzerat_nabizim = inzerat_nabizim.id_inzerat_nabizim
                     AND lokalita_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim = pronajem_pokoj_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim
                     AND osoba_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim = pronajem_pokoj_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim
                     AND typ_pokoje_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim = pronajem_pokoj_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim
                     AND vybaveni_pokoj_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim = pronajem_pokoj_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim
                     AND zarizeni_byt_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim = pronajem_pokoj_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim
                     AND lokalita_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim = pronajem_pokoj_nabizim.id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim;
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

If there's something not clear, ask me.

Comment: Alias names are great for readability. Could you use `ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Answer (score 2):

These are the possibilities listed [in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html):

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
    tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
    FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]

DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
    FROM tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
    USING table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

You are using `DELETE FROM ... WHERE`, which is not listed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get this. DELETE FROM ... WHERE is also possible, I saw examples of these so it's possible.

Comment: It's probably easier to just tweak your syntax and adopt one of the valid ones (either add stuff between `DELETE` and `FROM` to get #1 or add a `USING` clause to get #2) than to [start arguing with the MySQL parser](http://www.atariarchives.org/bcc2/showpage.php?page=133).